# Help in downloading dataset from Microsoft Research Open Data

Tags: data-request, download

I want to download the *Microsoft Speech Corpus (Indian languages)* dataset from https://msropendata.com/datasets/7230b4b1-912d-400e-be58-f84e0512985e

If I follow the instructions they tell me to use AzCopy (or Azure Storage Explorer), but when I use the URL that is generated, an error is shown. I tried to shorten it to https://msrodrdataset001.blob.core.windows.net/microsoftspeechcorpusindianlanguages and it shows that the location is empty , can someone guide me a little on how to download this dataset.

I don't want to deploy to Azure.

Edit

My URL links https://msrodrdataset001.blob.core.windows.net/microsoftspeechcorpusindianlanguages?sv=#####&sr=c&sig=#####&st=####&se=####&sp=rl

I Hope my format is good enough as I don't really know if any of those values are actually security keys except the sig , and that my description is good enough.
When I use this for AzCopy with Source and Dest, 
the error is

```
[2019-02-18 20:25:01][ERROR] The syntax of the command is incorrect. Invalid SAS token in parameter "Source". The syntax of the command is incorrect. Invalid SAS token in parameter "Source".
'sr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'sig' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'st' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'se' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'sp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When I take out the extra parameters

```
[2019-02-18 20:26:25][ERROR] Error parsing source location "https://msrodrdataset001.blob.core.windows.net/microsoftspeechcorpusindianlanguages": Source with location type Blob doesn't exist. For more details, please type "AzCopy /?:Source" or use verbose option /V.
```

I emailed Microsoft but they haven't replied yet, and was hoping someone here would be experienced with working with Microsoft Research

Comment: I went through the same steps and it seems this is a question for MS support (since this forum can't really answer questions about AzCopy or Azure Storage Explorer). If you get an answer, please post it here!

Comment: this also falls under not open data. if its tied to their services.